# Having problems with rand() in c

Tags: c, pointers, random, argv, argc

I am trying to write a program that simulates a pyjama picking. The main function need to get the amount of pyjamas and the kind of pyjamas as arguments(3 kinds of pyjamas: cheap, regular and expensive). Each pyjama has a name, size and price, the program will show the user the number of pyjamas and kind he entered as parameters. Then it will randomize 10 pyjamas as the following:
different names
different size (XS, S, M, L, XL)
price:
cheap: 10-30$
regular: 30-60$
expensive: 60-732.5$
Then the user will be able to choose the pyjamas that he liked until he reaches the number he entered in the arguments.
I wrote this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i, j;
    char* size = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
    float* price = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));
    char* name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
    printf("The number of pyjamas is: %s and the kind of pyjamas is: %s\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (argv[2] == "cheap")
        {
            *price = (float)(rand() % 20 + 10);
        }
        if (argv[2] == "regular")
        {
            *price = (float)(rand() % 30 + 30);
        }
        if (argv[2] == "expensive")
        {
            *price = (float)(rand() % (6725 + 600)) / 10;
        }
        *size = (char)(rand() % 5);
        if (size == 0)
        {
            size = "XS";
        }
        if (size == 1)
        {
            size = "S";
        }
        if (size == 2)
        {
            size = "M";
        }
        if (size == 3)
        {
            size = "L";
        }
        if (size == 4)
        {
            size = "XL";
        }
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            *name = (char)(rand() % 26 + 97);
        }
        printf("%f\n", price);
        printf("%s\n", size);
        printf("%s\n", name);
    }
    printf("%d", price);
    system("PAUSE");
    return (0);
}
```

I haven't done the picking part yet but the parts that I did do don't compile.
I get this error for lines 31, 35, 39 and 43:
warning C4047: '==' : 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
I also get this error for lines 14, 18 and 22:
warning C4130: '==' : logical operation on address of string constant
And this:
warning C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
And this:
warning C4100: 'argc' : unreferenced formal parameter
I don't know how to fix them please help!

**EDIT:**
The code now looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i, j;
    char* size = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
    float* price = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));
    char* name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
    int* choice = (int*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    printf("You entered %d parameters: The number of pyjamas is: %s and the kind of pyjamas is: %s\n", argc, argv[1], argv[2]);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[2], "cheap")==0)
        {
            *price = (float)(rand() % 20 + 10);
        }
        if (strcmp(argv[2], "regular")==0)
        {
            *price = (float)(rand() % 30 + 30);
        }
        if (strcmp(argv[2], "expensive")==0)
        {
            *price = (float)(rand() % (6725 + 600)) / 10;
        }
        switch (rand() % 5)
        {
        case 0:
            strcpy(size, "XS");
            break;
        case 1:
            strcpy(size, "S");
            break;
        case 2:
            strcpy(size, "M");
            break;
        case 3:
            strcpy(size, "L");
            break;
        case 4:
            strcpy(size, "XL");
            break;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            name[j] = (rand() % 26 + 'a');
        }
        name[j] = 0;
        printf("%f\n", price);
        printf("%s\n", size);
        printf("%s\n", name);
    }
    printf("Please pick %s pyjamas\n", argv[1]);
    if (choice)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", (choice + i));
        }
    }
    free(size);
    free(price);
    free(name);
    system("PAUSE");
    return (0);
}
```

I try to run it and all I get is a black cmd screen and this error **Unhandled exception at 0x5018FB53 (msvcr120d.dll) in Q6.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x555C3A44.**
When I choose break and stop the debugging, I check the error list and nothing appears there. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Don't `malloc` when you know the size (and when it's reasonably small); just do `char name[8]` etc.

Comment: OP: my compiler vomits out lotsa lotsa warnings when compiling this code - doesn't yours do the same?! You should understand the reason for the warning, and inspect your code and see if the warning is valid or not before proceeding any further!

Comment: Never mind, the problem was that I forgot to pass the parameters in the arguments. I still dont manage to randomize the price correctly though, it keeps printing 0.00000 its problem because its a pointer, I need help with that.

Comment: @AmnonHanuhov: since `price` is a pointer, you need to *dereference* it before passing it to `printf`: `printf("%f\n", *price );`

Answer (score 2):

Multiple issues:

1. You can't do string comparisons using the `==` operator.  You must use one of the `strcmp` or `strncmp` library functions instead, such as

   ```
   if (strcmp( argv[2], "cheap") == 0 )
   {
     price = rand() % 20 + 1; // no need for the cast, and we'll talk about 
                              // allocating price below
   }
   ```

   What's happening in your code is that you are comparing two *pointer* values (the address stored in `argv[2]` and the address of the string literal `"cheap"`, which are almost certainly not the same).
2. Just like you can't use `==` to compare strings, you can't use `=` to assign them.  What's happening is that you are assigning the *address* of your string literal (`"XS"`, `"S"`, etc.) to the variable *size*.  This has the unfortunate effect of overwriting the pointer value returned by the `malloc` call, resulting in a memory leak (more on this later).  Use the library functions `strcpy` or `strncpy` to assign strings:

   ```
   strcpy( size, "S" );
   ```
3. There's no reason to dynamically allocate any of `price`, `size`, or even `name`.  Just declare them as any normal variable:

   ```
   char name[4]; // result of rand() % 26 + 97 will never be more than 3 digits
   char size[3]; // size will never hold a string longer than 2 characters
   float price;
   ```
4. The code

   ```
   for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
   {
       *name = (char)(rand() % 26 + 97);
   }
   ```

   doesn't do what you expect; it will simply overwrite the first character in `name` multiple times.  It also assumes ASCII-specific encoding.  Change that to

   ```
   for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
   {
       name[j] = (rand() % 26 + 'a');
   }
   name[j] = 0;
   ```

   C strings must be 0-terminated (the last character in the sequence must be 0-valued).  Thus, an 8-element array of `char` can store a string of up to 7 characters.
5. The following code

   ```
   *size = (char)(rand() % 5);
   if (size == 0)
   {
       size = "XS";
   ```

   is *really* bad juju; you're trying to use the `size` variable for completely different purposes.  It "works" in the sense that `*size` can store an integral value, and you're immediately copying over it when you assign the string, but it's *bad* style.  Either use a different variable or switch on the result of the expression, like so:

   ```
   switch( rand() % 5 )
   {
     case 0:
       strcpy( size, "XS" );
       break;

     case 1:
       strcpy( size, "S" );
       break;

   // add code for remaining cases 
   }
   ```

It looks to me like you need to spend some time reading a basic C reference manual before proceeding with this project.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a pointer to a `char` variable. The `char` type in c, is not a string type, in fact there is no string type in c, you can't make `size = "X"`, because that is making a pointer to `"X"`.

You can try this

```
const char *size;
switch (rand() % 5)
 {
case 0:
    size = "XS";
    break;
case 1:
    size = "S";
    break;
case 2:
    size = "M";
    break;
case 3:
    size = "L";
    break;
case 4:
    size = "XL";
    break;
default:
    size = "Completely Unexpected";
    break;
 }
```

Also you have many other problems

1. Don't `malloc()` for a single value, and don't cast the return value of `malloc()`.
2. When you `printf("%f\n", price);` you invoke undefined behavior, because `price` is a pointer.
3. You can't compare strings in c with the `==` operator, you need `strcmp()` for that, so

   ```
   if (argv[2] == "cheap")
   ```

   has to be

   ```
   if (strcmp(argv[2], "cheap") == 0)
   ```

   comparing with `0` because `strcmp()` is used for sorting strings, since it returns an integer which is negative, zero or positive if the first string is smaller, equal or larger than the second, in their alphabetic order.

The c language, is not like the php or python languages where variable types are not important, you can do this in python

```
x = 3;
print(x)
x = "Hello"
print(x)
```

which would work correctly, in c variables are strogly typed, so you can't assing a variable of type `int` to a `const char *` for example.

Comment: Isn't the problem about assigning integers to a `char*` variable?  (line 31 is `if (size == 1)`) and `size` has type `char*`

Comment: I have to intialize all my variables dynamically. Except i and j.

Comment: @AmnonHanuhov that doesn't make sense at all, not at all.

Comment: And where did the part where I randomize a size to the variable size go?

Comment: `switch (rand() % 5)` you don't need to store the value to use it once.

Comment: @iharob that's a question I have as part of my homework, I didn't understand why should I do that either, but that's what the question demands.

Comment: @AmnonHanuhov Your assignment specifies that you should create pointless variables?

Comment: Where are you taking that class? If I were you I'd quit the class and search for another professor, it's not just an advice **I did it a few times when I was studying**, everyone said I was crazy, but a professor forcing you to do things wrong, will help you a lot to **waste** your time instead of learning.

Comment: @iharob well its more of a program, our professor is not the one writing the questions, there is somebody above him that writes the tasks.

Comment: @iharob Can you explain to me what did I do wrong in the srand function? I wrote the error in my question and I don't see anything wrong with the way I wrote the function

Comment: I don't see an error mentioning `srand`. Which line is it?

Comment: @Jongware C4244: 'function' : conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data its line 7